# Is it possible to create an App Clip using Swift in Xcode 11.2 or later without using Swift UI?

Tags: ios, swift, apple-appclips

I wanted to create an AppClip for my app which will be based on a QR code, but most tutorials online achieve this goal by creating the AppClip in SwiftUI. I want to create the AppClip using standard swift coding using `NSlayoutConstraints` without using storyboard. Is it possible?

Comment: You can expose `UIView`s to SwiftUI using `UIViewRepresentable`, so it is definitely possible. I'm not sure if you'll need the `UIViewRepresentable` or you can directly use `UIView`s, but it's definitely possible to achieve your goals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create App Clip using only `UIKit`.

1. Add a new target using the App Clip template.
2. Choose a product name,
3. Choose `Storyboard` as the `Interface`

### [image]

### Xcode 14-

Choose `UIKit App Delegate` as the Life cycle.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/app_clips/creating_an_app_clip_with_xcode

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you just need a short answer, then YES, it IS possible!

Just follow the [official documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/app_clips/creating_an_app_clip_with_xcode).